# User improvements suggestion: marking a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was looking for a way to mark a question that I like and is relevant to me but doesn't have any good answers yet and it seems like there is not yet functionality to do this. Was thinking this might be a good user improvement. Like a **"Tag"** button to tag a question so you can view them in the future. Maybe even add a section to the user's profile page so that you can review all your "Tagged" questions at a quick glance.

What do you think, is this a good improvement or is there already something built in that I just have been overlooking?

Comment: "Tag" might not be the best name for this. There is already another feature named "tag". Maybe "follow", or the already existing favorites feature...

Comment: Oh, and I thought this question was about marking questions as duplicates. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You could mark the question as a "favourite" - the star underneath the vote count. You can then access it from the "favorites" tab of your profile.

I know the terminology isn't quite right, but it will do the job.